# Get Email of an AD Group using C#

Tags: c#, principalcontext

I am trying to get the email of an AD group using C#, below is the code that I have.

```
using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, ADDomain))
{
    using (GroupPrincipal grp = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.Name, ADGroup))
    {
        var sams = from x in grp.GetMembers(true) select new { x.SamAccountName, };
        var users = from sam in sams.Distinct()
                    let usr = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.SamAccountName, sam.SamAccountName)
                    select new { usr.SamAccountName, usr.DisplayName, usr.EmailAddress };
    }
}
```

May I know how can I assign `usr.EmailAddress` to a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating an anonymous type, which means that the properties will have the same name as what you assigned in the `select` .Assuming that there is only meant to be one item in that list you can use this.

```
var result = users.SingleOrDefault()
if (result != null)
{
    var emailAddress = result.EmailAddress
}
```

Comment: in the event that there are multiple users, do I store `result` as a `list`, and using a loop to get email address for each user?

Comment: You can loop through your `users` collection